# Speed-up uTorrent when PC is idle?

Tags: firefox, download, speed, internet-connection, bittorrent

Is it possible that uTorrent will use its max speed when there is no other internet activity in the PC?

For example, if I'm using Firefox, uTorrent should be limited or have low priority for internet speed but once there is no more activity in Firefox, uTorrent should go back to full speed.

Comment: Google `QoS`...

Comment: @ta.speot.is AFAIK QoS usually applies to a network of computers right? Is there QoS software for a single desktop?

Comment: QoS applies to network traffic. Network traffic with normal priority (the default) is given higher priority than network traffic with lower priority. Turn on the QoS packet scheduler and create a rule to tag uTorrent's traffic as low priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your best bet would be either to use uTorrent's scheduler or, as per ta.speot.is's suggestion, try using QoS.

If you're looking for a QoS software instead of using your router, you could take a look at [NetBalancer](http://seriousbit.com/netbalancer/). With it, you could set uTorrent's priority to be lower than Firefox's (for example).